# custom structured storage IPropertySetStorage

Tags: c++, com, structured-storage

I'm trying to add a [`IPropertySetStorage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to an existing [`IStorage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file. The properties and their values I plan to write will be custom to my design (I may store a few ints, a few strings, etc). I am not trying to conform to any existing `IStorage` file type.

The API and its documentation feels targeted at existing file formats. This is custom, and thus (so far) the examples I have found have only been confusing.

Question(s)

On [`IPropertySetStorage::Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

1. (param 1) What `FMTID` do I pass? Can it be all zeros on the data fields? Can I just make it up?
2. (param 2) Can CLSID be a `nullptr`? If not, what should it be? Do I need to figure out what values the parent `IStorage` used?
3. (param 3) What propset flag would be best? I'm thinking because I'll be storing string, I should use `PROPSETFLAG_DEFAULT`.
4. (param 4) The `IStorage` handle is open for read (I'm running like a plugin to an existing runtime). My best guess right now is to use `STGM_DIRECT | STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE | STGM_CREATE`. But I've been getting [`STG_E_INVALIDFLAG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587%28v=prot.10%29.aspx)

Note, I have not been able to create a new `IPropertySetStorage` on the `IStorage` as of yet, but I have successfully created a custom `IStream`, and read from it on later opens.

Any links to tutorials more relevant to what I'm doing would be wonderfully appreciated.

**EDIT** Note that my code is called from an existing application, working on existing files. When my code is called, I am passed the file's root `IStorage`. Here is all of my code with that `IStorage` base.

```
rootStg->OpenStorage(name, nullptr, STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, nullptr, 0, &spIStg);
spIStg->QueryInterface(IID_IPropertySetStorage, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pPropSetStg));    

pPropSetStg->Create(
  ::FMTID_UserDefinedProperties, 
  nullptr, 
  PROPSETFLAG_DEFAULT, 
  STGM_CREATE|STGM_READWRITE|STGM_DIRECT|STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE , 
  &pPropStg);
```

Which, as I pointed out in #4, returns [`STG_E_INVALIDFLAG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587%28v=prot.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Please paste full code. My code works fine with your snippet.

Comment: @Xearinox As I was pasting all the relevant code, I noticed that I am opening my storage (I first create a child storage to house my parts) in READ mode, not RW (RW on create, but not when it's already there). This caused the create for the prop set to fail. It may seem silly, but if you post this detail as an answer (make sure to open your own storages in FW mode), I'd like to give you the credit, as it was your request for more info that helped me find it. Note, also, that I still would appreciate more information regarding the parameters as I detailed in my original question. Thank you.

Comment: Tommorow I do some research. I will give you results. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Special thanks to @Xearinox)

As I was pasting all the relevant code, I noticed that I am opening my storage (I first create a child storage to house my parts) in READ mode, not RW (RW on create, but not when it's already there). This caused the create for the prop set to fail.

```
// see STGM_READWRITE (fix)
rootStg->OpenStorage(name, nullptr, STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, nullptr, 0, &spIStg);
spIStg->QueryInterface(IID_IPropertySetStorage, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pPropSetStg));    

pPropSetStg->Create(
  ::FMTID_UserDefinedProperties, 
  nullptr, 
  PROPSETFLAG_DEFAULT, 
  STGM_CREATE|STGM_READWRITE|STGM_DIRECT|STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE , 
  &pPropStg);
```